# GridView. Как задать фиксированную ширину только одной колонке в GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

Как задать фиксированную ширину только одной колонке в `GridView`?

Comment: [копия вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608739/177345)