# Android. GridView. Как задать фиксированную ширину только одной колонке

Tags: android, gridview

Как задать для `GridView` фиксированную ширину только одной колонке.
В первой колонке идет текст, и на него нужно больше места, в остальных колонках отображаются цифры, соответственно места нужно меньше. Сейчас у меня ширина колонок определяется пропорционально, поэтому текст не влазит, а в колонках где цифры много свободного места.

Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Comment: @pavlofff, на указанный вами вопрос нет ни одного ответа.

Comment: Советую пользоваться RecyclerView, он куда более кастомизируемый, чем GridView, ширину колонки можно сделать при помощи своего кастомного GridLayoutManager

Comment: @Соколов Это не повод задавать еще один точно такой же. Один из них дожен быть удален.

Comment: @pavlofff на самом деле тот вопрос задан позже :)